# Doubles getting assigned to a List of Integer in java

Tags: java, generics

In the following code snippet:

```
        List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ints.add(1);
        ints.add(2);
        List<? extends Number> nums1 = ints;
        ints.add(3);
        ints.add(4);
        System.out.println("nums1 : " + nums1);
        List<? super Number> nums2 = (List<? super Number>) nums1;
        nums2.add(5.381);
        nums2.add(6);
        //ints.add(7.61762); // compilation error
        System.out.println("nums2 : " + nums2);
        System.out.println("ints : " + ints);
```

The List of Integer (ints here) is printed as : ints : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5.381, 6]
So it seems that something is wrong here ?

Actual O/P :

nums1 : [1, 2, 3, 4]

nums2 : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5.381, 6]

ints : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5.381, 6]   <-- Why 5.381 is fine in List

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That output is correct because at runtime type erasure will occur.

you've created 3 references `List<Integer> ints`,`List<? extends Number> nums1` and `List<? super Number> nums2` (mind the word reference) and one object `new ArrayList<Integer>();`.

Now remember that at runtime there is no `ArrayList<Integer>()` , the type will be erased and you get a `ArrayList` which can hold anything .Therefore your list end up containing `Integer`  and `double`.

Answer (score 1):

**`List<? extends Number>`:**

```
List<? extends Number> eExtend = new ArrayList<Number>();  
List<? extends Number> eExtend = new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<? extends Number> eExtend = new ArrayList<Double>();
```

In above code sample you can't add an **Integer** because `eExtend` could be pointing at a `List<Double>`.
And you can't add a **Double** because `eExtend` could be pointing at a `List<Integer>`.
Also you can't add a **Number** because `eExtend` could be pointing at a `List<Integer>`.

**`List<? super Number>`:**

```
List<? super Integer> eSuper = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 
List<? super Integer> eSuper = new ArrayList<Number>();
List<? super Integer> eSuper = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

In above code sample you can add an **Integer** because an **Integer** is allowed in any of above lists.
    And you can add an instance of a subclass of **Integer** because an instance of a subclass of **Integer** is allowed in any of the above lists.
But you can't add a **Double** because `eSuper` could be pointing at a `ArrayList<Integer>`.
    Also you can't add a **Number** because `eSuper` could be pointing at a `ArrayList<Integer>`.
    You can't add a **Object** because `eSuper` could be pointing at a `ArrayList<Integer>`.

```
List<? super Number> eSuper = new ArrayList<Number>();
```

You can add an instance of a subclass of **Number** because an instance of a subclass of **Number** allowed here. (**Double**,**Integer**)

Comment: So you mean when ints list is seen by System.out.println, its now seeing it as a list of Number instead of list of Integer and thus printing the number with decimal point. I can understand that its inserting a Double due to some reasoning, but not getting why the entire code further treats this as List of Number?

Comment: Can you run the example once and see this?

Comment: `ints.add(7.61762);` will give an error because you are trying to add a double value to `List<Integer> ints`. But `nums2` can have double values because `Double` and `Integer` are sub types of `Number` You should keep in mind that `list.add()` method only allows same type or sub type objects every time.

Comment: As I have mentioned in my answer If you change your code to `List<? super Integer> nums2 =  (List<? super Number>)nums1;` and try to add double value to your list `nums2.add(5.381);` again gives you an error.

Comment: `List<? super Integer> eSuper = new ArrayList<Number>();`
"you can't add a Double because `eSuper` could be pointing at a `ArrayList<Integer>`."

Comment: I have no problems in nums2.add(7.61762); this is perfectly fine. Whats bothering me is, why System.out.println("ints : " + ints); is printing ints : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5.381, 6], why its not printing ints : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] ?

Comment: When u do the following: System.out.print("looped ints : ");
        for(int i : ints) {
            System.out.print(i);
        }
        System.out.print("\n"); it will give runtime ClassCastException:java.lang.Double cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer So it seems that we are keeping a Double inside a list of integers. I think this should not be allowed, its a flawed implementation of generics.